# T4 with languages other than C# and VB

Tags: .net, f#, ironpython, t4

Is it posible to write T4 templates in other .NET languages? In particular I'm interested in F# and IronPython.

Comment: I'm not sure what relevance the language used in the template is, are you actually looking to use T4 templates to produce scaffolding for F# and IronPython or is it that you are only familiar with F# and Python so want to use those languages in the logic for the templates?

Comment: No. I'm familiar with C# also. I just wanted to use one of these two languages as a template language.

Comment: You can use C# in T4 to produce templates for F# and IronPython.

Comment: @Lazarus Yes, I know that. I wanted to know if there's a way to use F# or IronPython in T4, rather than a target language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc stipulates that only VB and C# are supported: [T4 Template Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586945.aspx), see the `language` attribute.

Comment: That's right, it's hardcoded at present.  We've never had enough customer demand to make it extensible for other languages as compared to doing other features.  My hunch is that if we did, the most popular languages might be dynamic languages that don't have a CodeDOM, which would require a chunk more effort to achieve in the core engine.

Answer (score 6):

I was complaining about this on twitter some time ago. It seems reasonable - afterall, T4 is just using CodeDOM provider! Anyway, Michael Hutchinson (from Mono team) [suggested using the implementation in Mono](http://twitter.com/#!/mjhutchinson/status/9281269036748801), which should be extensible.

I didn't look into that further, but I think it may be a way to go...