# F# templating engine similar to, say, mako?

Tags: f#

Does one exist?

The closest I've found is - https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine ; but I'm not overjoyed by it (in particular, I can't get it to work.)

Comment: I think it's fairly general .NET question, you can either use Razor (if you get it to work) or T4 text templates, in your case, the runtime text templates.

Comment: Ah; I forgot about T4 templates, thanks!

Comment: As requested, I moved the comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in comments, [T4 Text Templates (Run-Time Text Generation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx) is worth mentioning. [Unfortunately, it seems only C# and VB.NET are supported as template languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6290023/1180426), which means you'll have to create a separate C# project containing only templates and their backing models (e.g. DTO-like classes).

This project would be referenced and used by F# project. Good thing that such interop should be completely seamless :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to those mentioned by Patryk Ćwiek, I'd look at Fue.

Here's a basic template in Fue:

```
let html = "<div>{{{name}}}</div>"
let compiledHtml = init |> add "name" "Roman" |> fromText html
// compiledHtml now contains "<div>Roman</div>"
```

Fue is written in F# and has support for F# types such as options and Discriminated unions:

```
<!--Option types-->
<div fs-if="someOption.IsSome">{{{someOption.Value}}}</div>
<div fs-if="someOption.IsNone">Nothing</div>

<!--Discriminated Union
type UserAccess =
    | Anonymous
    | Admin of section:string
-->
    <div fs-du="item" fs-case="Anonymous">Anonymous</div>
    <div fs-du="item" fs-case="Admin(section)">{{{section}}}</div>
```

[Fue on Github](https://github.com/dzoukr/Fue)

[Fue on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fue/)